# ssh into terminal and save terminal output to file

Tags: python, file-io, save

I run the command

```
python code.py & > output.txt
```

This runs the program in the background and saves the output. The only problem is, when I open output.txt it's empty. I think this has something to do with the fact that I ssh into this terminal. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the ampersand after the stdout redirection:

```
$ python code.py > output.txt &
```